# How to get Regexp from EXSLT working in libxslt?

Tags: regex, xslt, exslt, libxslt

Has anyone got `Regexp` working in libxslt? When yes, how?

http://www.exslt.org/regexp/index.html

When using the command `xsltproc --dumpextensions` with the latest libxslt I'm not getting any Regexp support :-(

Comment: Joel Reed has written a libxslt-plugin for handling also regex in XSLT. Links are here: [filewatcher](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libxslt-plugin-regexp-0.3.tar.gz.281265.0.0.html) or here [at xmlsoft.org](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/plugins/libxslt-plugin-regexp-0.3.tar.gz) . But I have not tested them yet. Seems the development has been stopped for them ?!

Answer (score 1):

xsltproc includes {http://exslt.org/strings}replace already these days. Bind some prefix to that namespace, e.g. string, and then call string:replace().

You can get the list of extensions compiled into the xsltproc program using the shell command:

```
xsltproc --dumpextensions
```

If your libxsltproc is from the same build it should have the same extensions, I think.

Comment: yes, but http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/replace/index.html does not has the same power as regular expressions.