# EXSLT regexp in libXSLT Perl

Tags: perl, exslt, libxslt

I have already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952625/how-to-get-regexp-from-exslt-working-in-libxslt) question and I wanted to know if [exsl regexp](http://exslt.org/regexp/index.html) is at all available in libXSLT in Perl. (That page was last updated on 2001-06-30 which makes me wonder if the support was added later and the page was not updated).

If not, what are the alternatives for using regexp while performing XSLT 1.0 transformation using Perl-libXSLT ?

PS:
I am trying to solve a use case where I have to move from XSLT 2.0 (JAVA-Saxon) to XSLT 1.0 (Perl-libXSLT) transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perl distro *XML::LibXSLT* is based on the *libxslt* and *libexslt* C libraries. *libexslt*  [doesn't support the *regexp* module](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/EXSLT/html/libexslt-exslt.html). But it's possible to [register custom extension functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXSLT#register_function) which execute Perl code.